# Multiple conditionals with ng-show AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-show

I have a ng-repeat that builds a table from a web service. I render 6 values like this: `med:1 lab:1 pl:1` in one cell. I need to make a decision based on those 6 values. My `ng-repeat` code is like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(pid, value) in patient|groupBy:'pid'">
    <td>{{pid}}</td>
    <td ng-repeat="(disease, value) in patient|groupBy:'name'">
        <span ng-repeat="item in value|filterBy:['pid']:pid" ng-model="disease-conditial">
        {{item.src}}:{{item.total}}
        </span>
        <!--This is the code that I'm trying to make to work-->
        <span class="label label-danger" ng-show="
              (item.src == 'med' and item.total > 0) and
              (item.src == 'lab' and item.total > 0 and
              (item.src == 'pl' and item.total > 0))">Yes
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Please consider this sudo code. I need three conditions:
  `if src == med && total > 0`
   **and**
  `if src == lab && total > 0`
   **and**
  `if src == pl && total > 0`
     then **Yes**
  `if src == med && total == 0`
  `if src == lab && total > 0`
  `if src == pl && total > 0`
      then **Maybe**
  `if src == med && total == 0`
  `if src == lab && total == 0`
  `if src == pl && total == 0`
      then **No**

I was reading about ng-switch but this directive doesn't support conditionals with dynamic data `$scope.something == 1`
Does Angular has any built in directive where I can achieve this?

The data in the cell looks like this:

```
+-----------------+
|med:1 lab:1 pl:1 |
+-----------------+
```

I need to evaluate the value of med && the value of lab && the value of pl to make the decision of Yes, Maybe, No.

### Update 7 SEP 2016

The data that comes from the object is as follow:

```
Array[50]
0:Object
  $$hashKey:"object:18"
    name:"Alcoholism"
    pid:"1"
    src:"lab"
    total:"1"
    __proto__:Object
1:Object
  $$hashKey:"object:19"
  name:"Alcoholism"
  pid:"1"
  src:"med"
  total:"1"
  __proto__:Object
2:Object
  $$hashKey:"object:20"
  name:"Alcoholism"
  pid:"1"
  src:"pl"
  total:"0"
  __proto__:Object
```

Once again, scenario 1. `if med > 0 && lab >0 && pl >0 then Yes`. Scenario 2. `if med == 0 && lab > 0 && pl > 0 then Maybe`. Scenario 3. `if med == 0 && lab == 0 && pl == 0 then No`.

Comment: First of all, you shouldnt be doing this at the view, you should use a function in ng-show: ng-show="showData()", and do the conditions in the controller... Second is not "And", is &&

Comment: What do you mean the condition **maybe**?????? Use `&&` operators instead of `and`, and I agree with @GustavoGabriel, if you can create a function to define your logic in your controller, it will be much much easier.

Comment: Well if you remove the parentheses (operator precedence makes the parentheses useless when all conditions are 'and') you will see that item.src will never be 'med' and 'lab' and 'pl' at the same time, so the expression will always evaluate to false.

Comment: I change the `and` for `&&` and doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ng-switch with item.src like this:

```
  <div class="animate-switch-container" ng-switch on="item.src" ng-show="item.total > 0">
      <div ng-switch-when="med">med</div>
      <div ng-switch-when="lab">lab</div>
      <div ng-switch-when="pl">pl</div>
  </div>
```

With the ng-show in the entire div will make the same and validation.

Comment: This is a good clean example of both the [`ngSwitch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) and [`ngShow`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) directives

Comment: Fabio; the logic is as fallow... `ng-switch-when="med"` **and the value for med == 1** then Yes.

Comment: Even though it can be a good example of the use of ngSwitch and ngShow, this is not the answer to the question. It does not follow the logic (barely) explained in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just putting your conditions wrong. I'm doing some guessing here, but what I think you are trying to do is this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(pid, value) in patient|groupBy:'pid'">
    <td>{{pid}}</td>
    <td ng-repeat="(disease, value) in patient|groupBy:'name'">
        <span ng-repeat="item in value|filterBy:['pid']:pid" ng-model="disease-conditial">
        {{item.src}}:{{item.total}}
        </span>
        <!--This is the code that I'm trying to make to work-->
        <span class="label label-danger" ng-show="
              ((item.src == 'med' || item.src == 'lab' || item.src == 'pl') and item.total > 0)">
            Yes
        </span>

        <span class="label label-danger" ng-show="
              ((item.src == 'med' && item.total == 0) || (item.src == 'lab' and item.total > 0) || (item.src == 'pl' and item.total > 0))">
            Maybe
        </span>

        <span class="label label-danger" ng-show="
              ((item.src == 'med' || item.src == 'lab' || item.src == 'pl') and item.total == 0)">
            No
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

It is not a problem with the `ng-show` directive, it is a problem with the conditions inside it.

Comment: Let me try that Alvaro. I'm wondering why I got a -1 vote for this question?

Comment: I don't know, I'm not who gave the negative vote to you. Maybe because the problem itself does not relate to AngularJS but with the boolean condition but, honestly, I don't know. The best way to avoid downvotes is to follow [StackOverflow's question guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Good luck with your try!

Comment: Alvaro; I think you are missing a `(`. In the first line you are closing right after the `0` but I don't see where should opened. Any way, I tried that line of code and is rendering Yes in all my cells. I moved the missing `(` right before `item.total` and ` at the very begging `item.src` and got the same result, all cells with `Yes`

Comment: Please, try the solution now. There was a missing '(' at the very beggining of the fist condition.

Comment: Sorry again, there was another '(' at the beggining of the third condition :). I edited my answer.

Comment: It is rendering `Yes, Maybe, No` in all the cells. At some point in my code I had the same outcome. For some reason `ng-show` can't discriminate the values and create the conditions.

Comment: Now I have to go to bed, a little bit late here in Spain :), but it makes sense. Tomorrow I'll try to take a look if you didn't get any successfull answer. Kind regards.

Comment: In the meantime, try to get us a working plunker which reproduces the error with some representative data to make some testing.

Comment: Thank you Alvaro!!

Comment: Hi again Gilbert. I'm having a quick look at your question again and I notice that something must be wrong either with the logic or with de way you iterate over your data. The conditions I gave to you don't make much sense because if item.src === 'med' and item.total === 0, it will match two of the conditions. Please, edit your question adding a full example of the JSON object you are iterating over (I mean your 'patient' object/array) to take a look at it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ill prefer you to get single value from controller which you want to display on view but ng-bind can also help you render required data

```
<span class="label label-danger" ng-bind="item.total>0 && (item.src === 'med' || item.src === 'lab' || item.src === 'pl')?'yes':'no'"> </span>
```

Comment: Muslim; let me try your solution.

Comment: Your code returns just two conditions, My problem has three instead.